# For all $[a]$,$[b]\in{\mathbb{Z}m}$, if $[a][b]=[0]$, then $[a]=[0]$ or $[b]=[0]$. Prove that if $S$ is true, then $m$ is prime.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let $m\in{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $m>1$. Consider the implication $S$: For all $[a]$,$[b]\in{\mathbb{Z}m}$, if $[a][b]=[0]$, then $[a]=[0]$ or $[b]=[0]$. Prove that if $S$ is true, then $m$ is prime.

How should I go about solving this implication?

Anything is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Contrapose it...

Comment: If $m$ is composite, then $m=st$ for some $s,t \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $s,t > 1$ and $[s][t] = [0]$.

Comment: How do I prove the contrapositive?